# How to convert country level geojson using QGIS using data from naturalearthdata .org

Tags: geojson, qgis

I have to create 170  topojson for 170 countries from a single geojson file.
I am using shape file from naturalearthdata.org admin 1 state county level map.
I use **QGIS** desktop software to create geojson file .

1.How to create  geojson file for 170 country using QGIS **individually**(170 geojson file) I am able to convert earthdata admin 1 level data to single geojson which covers all countries in the world.

2.Is there any other easy tool where i can create geojson file from shapefile, as for 170 countries it involves  a  lot of manual work to convert. Can you point me to some sites where
this step is already done and i can start using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Qgis divide your shapefile into countries by country ID with:
   Vector > Data Management > Split Vector layer
2. Change into the directory with the 170 shapefiles and use [topojson commandline](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference) to directly convert to topojson:

Linux/Mac

```
for f in *.shp; do topojson -o  `basename $f .shp`.json $f; done
```

Win

```
for %f in (*shp) do topojson -o %~nf.json %f
```

PS. You might consider posting GIS related questions on https://gis.stackexchange.com/